# Updating text within VBA code automatically

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet called `Team-A`, which contains VBA modules. I also have a macro in this sheet that is run to create a duplicate of the same spreadsheet, but data imported for another team. It then saves it as `Team-B`. So then I have two sheets, `Team-A` and `Team-B`.

The issues is that I then have to manually edit the VBA scripts/Macros in the new sheet to point them to `Team-B`.

My query: Is it possible to have this manual update (of the VBA code) done via the same script that creates the new sheet?

Comment: If your code is written to take this into account then you shouldn't need to edit it in the copy of the sheet.  It would help to post the relevant parts of your current module.

Comment: Are you saying you put macro in the Sheet object instead of a Module? Or is it a Workbook? You should make code more generic where the Worksheet is the ActiveSheet (generally a bad idea, but depending on what your code is to achieve).

Comment: Tim & Patrick, thanks for the input. I've modified the code to build the workbook names dynamically based on the 'current' workbook. Appreciate  you advice!

Answer (score 0):

Edit the code to point to ActiveSheet instead of "Team-A" sheet and you should be good